# Firefox invalid date format: rails server and angularJS client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, date, firefox

I'm getting a few metadata information from rails server which have a date time attribute of phone picture.
I want to show that date in local format with angularJS, this is what I got from rails as an example date:

> 2018-05-09 09:46:33 UTC

This the code in angularJS side :

```
getDateTimeOriginal: =>
      if @metadata? and @metadata.date_time_original?
        dateTime = new Date(@metadata.date_time_original)
        moment(dateTime).format('DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm A')
```

it 's working perfectly in Chrome but I got an invalid date in Firefox  !

Comment: Because that is an invalid ISO date format. Chrome is a bit more lenient than some browsers when formats are invalid. Use second argument of `moment()` to tell it what input format is or return a valid ISO format from server

Comment: thanks @charlietfl for you answer , can you be more specific in what input format is, or give me an example ? thanks

Comment: Is explained in the moment docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, [according to the MDN page on Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), parsing date strings through the date constructor or date parse shoud be avoided:

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

And since your datetime format is not [ISO8601 compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), you'll get the same kind of issue if you try to provide your datetime string to moment directly.

---

According to me, you should parse your date string with moment (use the `parse` method + specify the format). Be careful and use `moment.utc` since you have a UTC datetime. Then you can return a JS Date (local date) and rely on its `toLocale...` methods :

- `toLocaleTimeString()` : [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toLocaleTimeString)
- `toLocaleDateString()` : [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toLocaleDateString)
- `toLocaleString()` : [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toLocaleString)

This could give something like (I translate your coffeescript code to regular Javascript/Ecmascript so that it can be more useful to people coming accross this answer):

```js
function localizedDatetime(datetime_original, locale) {
  let parsedDatetime = moment.utc(datetime_original, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');
  return parsedDatetime.toDate().toLocaleString(locale);
}

const input = '2018-05-09 09:46:33 UTC';
const fr = localizedDatetime('2018-05-09 09:46:33 UTC', 'fr-FR');
const en = localizedDatetime('2018-05-09 09:46:33 UTC', 'en-US');

console.log("Input: ", input);
console.log(">> FR:", fr);
console.log(">> EN:", en);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```